# Uncaught Error when append data by Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, input

I have just learnt Google Apps Script a week to build a small online survey for my work.

Everything work fine, until I added 1 more question about taking Photo in the Index. Before that, it worked OK with 1 element taking Photo, but when I added 1 more element than an "Uncaught" error appear. I have tried to find this issue but it seems my English is not good enough to "google" right search key and didn't find any same error.

Please see my Index HTML code below: The error occurs when I added element with id "ds_q_Q06"

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=10" />
  <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />
  <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#0072C6" />
  <title>GAS Question Templates</title>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css"  />
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
    
    <?!= include('CSS'); ?>
    <?!= include('JS'); ?>
    <?!= include('Json_data'); ?>
    <?!= include('Routing'); ?>

    
    
  </head>
  <body>
    <form class="form-survey test" id="mainForm">
      <div class="survey-info" style="display:none;">
        <input type="text" name="respID" id="respId" class="respId" ></input>
        <input type="text" name="currentPage" id="currentPage" class="currentPage" ></input>
        <input type="text" name="routing" id="routing" class="routing" ></input>
      </div>

      <div class="main-content">
        <div class="dsDropDown ds-question" name="ds_q_Q01_1" id="ds_q_Q01_1">
          <div class="q-question">
            1. Điểm bán:
          </div>
          <div class="q-error hidden">
            <span class="dsErrorText"></span>
          </div>
          <div class="q-info hidden">
            <span class="dsInfoText"></span>
          </div>
          <div class="q-answer">
            <select class="">
              <option disabled selected value>Vui lòng chọn...</option>
              <option value="Điểm bán mở cửa - Khảo sát TC">Điểm bán mở cửa - Khảo sát TC</option>
              <option value="Điểm bán không tìm thấy">Điểm bán không tìm thấy</option>
              <option value="Điểm bán thay đổi KD">Điểm bán thay đổi KD</option>
              <option value="Điểm bán đóng cửa">Điểm bán đóng cửa</option>
              <option value="Điểm bán mở cửa - Từ chối hợp tác">Điểm bán mở cửa - Từ chối hợp tác</option>
            </select>
          </div>
          <div class="q-true-answer">
              <input type="text" name="answer" class="hidden answer" ></input>
          </div>
        </div>


        <div class="dsImage ds-question" name="ds_q_Q01_2" id="ds_q_Q01_2">
          <div class="q-question">
            Chụp hình
          </div>
          <div class="q-error hidden">
            <span class="dsErrorText"></span>
          </div>
          <div class="q-info hidden">
            <span class="dsInfoText"></span>
          </div>
          <div class="q-answer">
            <input type="file" accept="image/*" name="file" id="Q02_img"></input>
            
            <div class="button">
              <div class="btnUpload" >Upload</div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="q-true-answer">
              <input type="text" name="answer" class="hidden answer" ></input>
          </div>
        </div>


        <div class="dsText ds-question" name="ds_q_Q02" id="ds_q_Q02">
          <div class="q-question">
            2. Ghi chú
          </div>
          <div class="q-error hidden">
            <span class="dsErrorText"></span>
          </div>
          <div class="q-info hidden">
            <span class="dsInfoText"></span>
          </div>
          <div class="q-answer q-true-answer">
            <textarea type="text" name="answer" class="answer" ></textarea>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>

      <div class="main-content">
        <div class="dsDropDown ds-question" name="ds_q_Q03_1" id="ds_q_Q03_1">
          <div class="q-question">
            3. Tên điểm bán / Biển hiệu:
          </div>
          <div class="q-error hidden">
            <span class="dsErrorText"></span>
          </div>
          <div class="q-info hidden">
            <span class="dsInfoText"></span>
          </div>
          <div class="q-answer">
            <select class="">
              <option disabled selected value>Vui lòng chọn...</option>
              <option value="Đúng">Đúng</option>
              <option value="Sai">Sai - Cập nhật tên điểm bán mới</option>
            </select>
          </div>
          <div class="q-true-answer">
              <input type="text" name="answer" class="hidden answer" ></input>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="dsText ds-question optional" name="ds_q_Q03_2" id="ds_q_Q03_2">
          <div class="q-question">
          </div>
          <div class="q-error hidden">
            <span class="dsErrorText"></span>
          </div>
          <div class="q-info hidden">
            <span class="dsInfoText"></span>
          </div>
          <div class="q-answer q-true-answer">
            <input type="text" name="answer" class="answer" placeholder="Nhập tên điểm bán..." ></input>
          </div>
        </div>
        
      </div>

      <div class="main-content">
        <div class="dsDropDown ds-question" name="ds_q_Q04_1" id="ds_q_Q04_1">
          <div class="q-question">
            4. Địa chỉ:
          </div>
          <div class="q-error hidden">
            <span class="dsErrorText"></span>
          </div>
          <div class="q-info hidden">
            <span class="dsInfoText"></span>
          </div>
          <div class="q-answer">
            <select class="">
              <option disabled selected value>Vui lòng chọn...</option>
              <option value="Đúng">Đúng</option>
              <option value="Sai">Sai</option>
            </select>
          </div>
          <div class="q-true-answer">
              <input type="text" name="answer" class="hidden answer" ></input>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="dsText ds-question optional" name="ds_q_Q04_2" id="ds_q_Q04_2">
          <div class="q-question">
          </div>
          <div class="q-error hidden">
            <span class="dsErrorText"></span>
          </div>
          <div class="q-info hidden">
            <span class="dsInfoText"></span>
          </div>
          <div class="q-answer q-true-answer">
            <input type="text" name="answer" class="answer" placeholder="Nhập địa chỉ..." ></input>
          </div>
        </div>
        
      </div>

      <div class="main-content">
        <div class="dsSingle ds-question" name="ds_q_Q05" id="ds_q_Q05">
          <div class="q-question">
            5. Single Question
          </div>
          <div class="q-error hidden">
            <span class="dsErrorText"></span>
          </div>
          <div class="q-info hidden">
            <span class="dsInfoText"></span>
          </div>
          <div class="q-answer">
            <ul>
              <li>
                <input type="radio" name="ds_sa_Q01" id="Q01_C1" class="dsSingleChoice"></input>
                <label for="Q01_C1" class="answerLabel">Câu 2</label>
              </li>
              <li>
                <input type="radio" name="ds_sa_Q01" id="Q01_C2" class="dsSingleChoice"></input>
                <label for="Q01_C2" class="answerLabel">Câu 3</label>
              </li>
              <li>
                <input type="radio" name="ds_sa_Q01" id="Q01_C3" class="dsSingleChoice"></input>
                <label for="Q01_C3" class="answerLabel">Câu 4</label>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="q-true-answer">
              <input type="text" name="answer" class="hidden answer" ></input>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>


      **<div class="main-content">
        <div class="dsImage ds-question" name="ds_q_Q06" id="ds_q_Q06">
          <div class="q-question">
            6. Take Photo
          </div>
          <div class="q-error hidden">
            <span class="dsErrorText"></span>
          </div>
          <div class="q-info hidden">
            <span class="dsInfoText"></span>
          </div>
          <div class="q-answer">
            <input type="file" accept="image/*" id="Q06_img"></input>

            <div class="button">
              <div class="btnUpload" >Upload</div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="q-answer q-true-answer">
            <input type="text" name="answer" class="answer" ></input>
          </div>
        </div>
        
      </div>**


      <div class="main-content">
        <div class="dsDropDown ds-question" name="ds_q_Q07" id="ds_q_Q07">
          <div class="q-question">
            7. Drop Down Question
          </div>
          <div class="q-error hidden">
            <span class="dsErrorText"></span>
          </div>
          <div class="q-info hidden">
            <span class="dsInfoText"></span>
          </div>
          <div class="q-answer">
            <select class="">
              <option disabled selected value>------</option>
            </select>
          </div>
          <div class="q-true-answer">
              <input type="text" name="answer" class="hidden answer" ></input>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>

      <div class="main-content">
        <div class="dsText ds-question" name="ds_q_Q08" id="ds_q_Q08">
          <div class="q-question">
            8. Text / Search Question
          </div>
          <div class="q-error hidden">
            <span class="dsErrorText"></span>
          </div>
          <div class="q-info hidden">
            <span class="dsInfoText"></span>
          </div>
          <div class="q-answer q-true-answer">
            <input type="text" name="answer" class="answer" ></input>
          </div>
        </div>
        
      </div>

      <div class="main-content">
        <div class="dsSearch ds-question" name="ds_q_Q09" id="ds_q_Q09">
          <div class="q-question">
            9. Text / Search Question
          </div>
          <div class="q-error hidden">
            <span class="dsErrorText"></span>
          </div>
          <div class="q-info hidden">
            <span class="dsInfoText"></span>
          </div>

          <div class="q-answer q-true-answer">
            <input type="text" name="answer" class="answer" ></input>
          </div>
        </div>
        
      </div>
      


      <div class="ds-navigator">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td class="left"><div class="button dsPrev">Previous Page</div></td>
              <td class="right"><div class="button dsNext">Next Page</div></td>
            </tr>
            
          </tbody>
        </table>
        
        
      </div>
      <div class="survey-done hidden"><div class="dsEndMessage">Thank you for submitting!</div></div>
      <div class="survey-loading hidden">
        <div class="loader">
          <div class="loader-wheel"></div>
          <div class="loader-text"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is my app script that input data when click on submit button

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Index').evaluate().setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME).addMetaTag('viewport', 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1');
}


function include(filename) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename).getContent();
}


function uploadFiles(imageFile) {
   //var folderId = getFolderID("App_Img");
    
    var blob = Utilities.newBlob(imageFile.bytes, imageFile.mimeType, imageFile.filename);
    
   
    
    var file = DriveApp.getFolderById("ID_FOLDER");

    try {
      var child = file.getFoldersByName(imageFile.folderName).next();
    }
    catch(e){
      var child = file.createFolder(imageFile.folderName);
    }

    child.createFile(blob);

    
    return {fileURL:file.getUrl(),fileDir:imageFile.fileDir};
}


function getFolderID(folderName)
{
  var folders = DriveApp.getFolders();
  while (folders.hasNext()) {
   var folder = folders.next();
   if(folder.getName() == folderName)
   {
    return folder.getId();
   }
 }
}

**
function inputData(formSurvey){
  
  var url = "URL_GOOGLE_SHEETS";
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  var ws = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  Logger.log(ws.getName());
  console.log(ws.getName());

  var data = [];
  for (var i = 0; i<formSurvey.answer.length; i++){
    data.push(formSurvey.answer[i]);
  }

  Logger.log(data.join(";"));
  console.log(data.join(";"));
  //ws.appendRow(data);

}
**
```

Here is my JS when click Submit button (last page)

```
function endSurvey(){
    $(".survey-loading").show(0).delay(5000).hide(0);
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(submitSuccess).inputData($("#mainForm")[0]);
    
  }
  
  function submitSuccess(){
    $(".survey-done").toggleClass("hidden",false);
  }
```

The error is quite weird , without any more information.
[image]

Please help me on this.

Comment: Here is the link if any one need to check: https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbzptw5DwwzsmYQNwLw7o_EU9v0znNVAsJnMWJFnNaDj42GCMO3zrJh7/exec

Comment: If you press the ᐅ button next to the error what does it show? Also can you click where it says :`...user__vi.js:55` to see what line that fails?

Comment: Thanks for response, when I press the |> button, the detail shows below 

`
Uncaught 
Xd @ 1920352480-mae_html_user_bin_i18n_mae_html_user__vi.js:55
jf @ 1920352480-mae_html_user_bin_i18n_mae_html_user__vi.js:75
(anonymous) @ 1920352480-mae_html_user_bin_i18n_mae_html_user__vi.js:16
og.P @ 1920352480-mae_html_user_bin_i18n_mae_html_user__vi.js:104
Qd @ 1920352480-mae_html_user_bin_i18n_mae_html_user__vi.js:51
Md @ 1920352480-mae_html_user_bin_i18n_mae_html_user__vi.js:52
Kd.b @ 1920352480-mae_html_user_bin_i18n_mae_html_user__vi.js:48
`

Comment: And when I click to the link `...user__vi.js:55` , it's a minified file and quite long that I cannot post in the comment

Comment: And 1 more info that, when I remove the error element (ds_q_Q06), everything works OK, and the log "Logger.log(ws.getName());" in function inputData can log the info. But when that element is added, the log "Logger.log(ws.getName());" is not called as there's nothing log.

Comment: Yeah that is not a very helpful error...I can't think of what it might be... I am trying to reproduce this on my account but I am missing the example sheet and drive folder. Can you create some samples with repro steps so I can recreate this error? See [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). That or try and modifying the HTML element that you are adding. Maybe one of the attributes is causing an error for some reason. Also, usually the chrome dev tools has a function to unminify files so you can see what line fails.

Comment: I am not really sure how to make minimal reproducible with Google Apps script, as I just learned it 1 week ago. So I tried to copy all my code in this project to text files and send them here. Could it help? https://drive.google.com/file/d/1pgL38n3Bf0nuqn_aLPBs91RwLtaG7PMM/view?usp=sharing

Comment: What about the spreadsheet and the drive folder, do these need to be set up in any way? Also, can you unminify the JS file in dev tools to see the failing line? https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/pretty-print

Comment: Spreadsheet and Drive folder is already set up as the script work normally when remove "that element". I have unminify the JS file and here is the failing line `function Xd(a, b) {
        b = Error(b);   \\\ error occurs here
        b.name = a;
        return b
    } `

Comment: Right but I mean that I would need to set up the spreadsheet and drive on my account, can you share copies without any sensitive information? Also, an idea => Maybe use Goolge Forms for this? You can also use Apps Script with forms and link the results to a spreadsheet.

Comment: Hi iansedano, firstly, thank you for your effort these days, it's really motivate me to test deeplier. Secondly, I just want to inform that I have found a work around solution. By only creating the 1 "input file" element to the end of DOM and append that element to "dsImage" div when it's showed. Therefore, in the end, there's only 1 input file element in DOM and everything works again. BTW, I still wonder why there's error if there are more than 1 input file element :(

Comment: Check my answer here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/66059836/10445017 - check if your executions page has more info

Comment: Thanks, i have just read it, but when the error occurs, in the execution page, there isn’t any log of server side Apps script function in there. Therefore I know that the error come from that function but dont know which error is it.

Comment: Are you sure that you don't have any filters on the executions or something?

Comment: Sorry for late response, I just got sick last weekend. Yes, there is no filter at all (as I also don't know there 's filter function for execution) . When there isn't that element, the execution shows log of server side function (importData) , but when I include that element, the error occurs, and execution doesn't show log of function ImportData

Comment: I don't know in that case... without being able to reproduce it on my account, I can't say what it could be. Sorry and good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I've faced a similar situation with an "uncaught" console error after running some specific server side function. After a day of searching where the problem is, in my case It was caused by running the google app script from one account while logged in chrome to another one.
Once I changed and opened the app from the same account as logged in to Chrome, the problem disappeared.

Comment: yeah, GAS usually return the "uncaught" error for many types of error. For the problem in this topic, I cannot solve it but make another way to approach it by just use 1 "input type file" element only and re-use it for each page that need to upload image.

Comment: I'm facing the same error right now. I had my code working well to include html content. after sometime, I'm now not able to use the same code again `function include` for no reason. I'm about to get crazy `Uncaught  at include (Code:29)` if I get any solution I'll list it here