# Google Apps Script uncaught error in Chrome Console

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a simple data entry tool on my Sheet that's an HTML form and then it runs through the fields in the form and posts them to the sheet. The utility works absolutely fine on my home computer. I noticed when a colleague tried it, it failed. I checked his console and there was an uncaught error. I tried the utility on my work computer and it also failed to push the values to the sheet. Almost like there is some type of issue with the google.script.run function? I have had it work for others on different networks. Attached is what it throws in the Chrome console. Not a very descriptive or useful error. I don't get this on my home computer.

My JavaScript:

```
<script>
  // Prevent forms from submitting.
  function preventFormSubmit() {
    const forms = document.querySelectorAll('form');
    for (var i = 0; i < forms.length; i++) {
      forms[i].addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      });
    }
  }
  window.addEventListener('load', preventFormSubmit);
  
  function handleFormSubmit(formObject) {
      $("#formType").val($('title').text());
      google.script.run.processForm(formObject);
      $(".selectpicker").val("default"); // Reset select
      $(".selectpicker").selectpicker("refresh"); // Refresh select
      $("input").val(""); // Reset input values
      $("textarea").val(""); // Reset input values
      $("#waiver").parents().eq(1).css({ display: "none" });
      if ($('title').text() === "PT Credit") {
          var table = $("#credit_table")
          table.parent().css({ display: "none" });
          table.empty();
      }
  }
</script>
```

[image: Error Image]

Comment: Can you share what you have tried? Or a sample of your code?

Comment: Is this the same issue as this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66008840/uncaught-error-when-append-data-by-google-apps-script ? I.e are you working with the same project or is this two separate instances of this error?

Comment: @iansedano This is a different project, I didn't see that question but it does look like it's the same issue.

Comment: @RayGun I posted the JavaScript file that is supposed to run the .gs code on submit but it looks like when the issue occurs it does not do that. Works fine on my end.

Comment: I come from the topic that iansedano mentioned. Could I see your index, we might find out something from it?

Answer (score 0):

#### Check your Apps Script Executions

After some experimenting I have found that whenever I had an `uncaught` error in the client console, it was always because one of the server side Apps Script functions were failing.

Go to script.google.com > My Executions

[image]

Or to your specific project, the executions page:

[image]

Seeing as the error only appears on another system, it is likely to be account related. Though there should be more info in the executions page as to why it failed.